# Access 2013 Applying Multiple Filters to a Form via a Button

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, filter, ms-access-2013

I am trying to make a searchable form in Access.  The set up will be 5-6 text boxes, a couple toggles, and one button.  You enter whatever information you have into the text boxes, click the button, and only the records that meet ALL the criteria are displayed.

[Current Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f1WJ.jpg)

I found some code on the internet that seemed to give me all I would need:

http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62code.html

But when I put it in, it returns nothing at all.  I've only put in one text box so far, to make sure I get it correct before I waste time adding a bunch of AND's.  Here is all my code currently:

```
Private Sub SearchAll_Click()

If Not IsNull(Me.txtCityCounty) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([City/County] Like "" * " & Me.txtCityCounty & " * "")"

    Me.Filter = strWhere
    Me.FilterOn = True

    End If

End Sub
```

If it is helpful, "SearchAll" is my button, "txtCityCounty" is the textbox, "City/County" is the field name.

When I try to enter text in my text box and click my button, it returns nothing and all my embedded text boxes below disappear, as if it was filtering something that did not appear (which, I can assure you, is not the case.  I was entering in "Salt").

What am I missing? Is there an easier way to go about this project?

Comment: Here is the database that corresponds with that code I found:  http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this without all the extra quotes

"([City/County] Like ' * " & Me.txtCityCounty & " *' )"

And if you want you can even get rid of the IF statement by just using:

strwhere = nz("([City/County] Like ' * " & Me.txtCityCounty & " *' )","")

Answer (score 0):

Consider building up a filter string conditionally and using the [DoCmd.ApplyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx) method:

```
Dim filterString As String

filterString = "1 = 1"                    

If Not IsNull(Me.txtCityCounty) Then
   filterString = filterString & "([City/County] Like '*" & Me.txtCityCounty & "*')"
End if
If Not IsNull(Me.txtAgePopulation) Then
   filterString = filterString & "([Age/Population] Like '*" & Me.txtAgePopulation & "*')"
End if

If Not IsNull(Me.txtServiceType) Then
   filterString = filterString & "([ServiceType] Like '*" & Me.txtServiceType & "*')"
End if

If Not IsNull(Me.txtInsurance) Then
   filterString = filterString & "([Insurance] Like '*" & Me.txtInsurance & "*')"
End if

If Not IsNull(Me.txtProviders) Then
   filterString = filterString & "([Providers] Like '*" & Me.txtProviders & "*')"
End if

DoCmd.ApplyFilter , filterString
```